# Mcrypt on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mcrypt

I want to use mcrypt encryption on iPhone. I don't have problem using it on the iPhone Simulator which uses i386 architecture. iPhone uses armv7s architecture and mcrypt doesn't seem to support it. I installed it with mac ports by this command: sudo install mcrypt +universal. So it should be 'universal'. Is there any way to get it working on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

The `+universal` flag on MacPorts is related to **OS X universal binaries**. It has nothing to do with iOS.

So you'll get only binaries for OS X, with multiple architectures (i386, x86_64, maybe PPC).
Not ARM binaries for iOS.

If you need such a library on iOS, your best solution is to grab the sources and compile them by yourself using Xcode, into an iOS static library target.

You'll find many tutorials about this on the web.

Comment: ok, since this doesn't seem very easy i used 'CommonCrypto' library for encrypting. but thanks for the answer.