# AES256 encrypt in objective C to mach with php rijndael_256 ECB_MODE

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a json in AES256 in objective C to send to one server and php decrypt it using the following line:

**MCRYPT_DECRYPT (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $ key, base64_decode ($ ha), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, NULL));**

took several days searching and testing and I have not gotten results. The code I'm using is this:

```
- (NSString *)AES256EncryptData:(NSData *) datos {

    //NSData * datos = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    UIApplication *aplicacion = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) aplicacion.delegate;

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [delegate.appKey getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [datos length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);


    size_t numBytesEncrypted;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL,
                                          [datos bytes],
                                          [datos length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);


    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSData *returnData  = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        return [returnData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the key is 32 bytes length. I've change the key type but the result is the same. Any idea to set the padding? Averything that I've tested is wrong and the result is NULL

Comment: I have found that I can decrypt the result in PHP with Rijndael_128 not Rijndael_256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try forever given the encryption algorithm you are using. You are currently using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`, which is the Rijndael block cipher with 256 *block size*. You should be using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` (otherwise known as AES), and then perform the [PKCS#7 unpadding yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314901/how-to-add-remove-pkcs7-padding-from-an-aes-encrypted-string).

You should indeed supply exactly the right amount of key bytes as well, which should be either 16, 24 or 32 bytes for AES. And the key bytes obviously must match the ones you are using in your C# code.

---

If you cannot change the server code you should make / compile mcrypt for IOS and implement the same functions for that particular API. At least it will be compatible. Unfortunately it seems you will have to [do the porting yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896731/mcrypt-on-iphone).

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the server configuration

Comment: Changed the answer, please give the server developers a good kick from me, their code is not safe and doesn't use any kind of standard cryptography.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm aware that this is more or less a "negative" answer, but I'm afraid that's not something I can change.